# When I hit run I get this

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings remapped class cache for b4ieilm7vkknhwvoai8y4gzba (C:\Users\scc.gradle\caches\5.4.1\scripts-remapped\settings_82uzw4y09pfsg18is5z97qxmt\b4ieilm7vkknhwvoai8y4gzba\settingsdcd040730888da95d185715568c9cc57).

> Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Flutter apps\flutter_app\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\scc.gradle\caches\5.4.1\scripts\b4ieilm7vkknhwvoai8y4gzba\settings\settingsdcd040730888da95d185715568c9cc57).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 57

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

Comment: Your question barely shows any detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run flutter clean in cmd or using android studio

```
Flutter clean
```

if it is not work run flutter upgrade and then run flutter clean

```
flutter upgrade
```